# Configuring Azure b2C authentication with custom settings

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to create an azure b2c authentication for my Xamarin Forms Android application including multi factor authentication. With the following constraints.

- I need to restrict / hide **forgot password & Sign-up option** from login page.
- Multifactor – Authentication, I need only **sms option**. I don’t want to go with call & email option.

How I can add these restrictions to my authentication-login page?

I see below set of policies in Portal but, I don’t know how to configure it. Can anyone help me to configure this Policies.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to restrict / hide forgot password & Sign-up option from login page.

This one is easy, just create a **Sign-In** policy (not Sign-up or Sign-in)

> Multifactor – Authentication, I need only sms option. I don’t want to
>   go with call & email option.

AFAIK you can only enable or disable it. I also don't find any option to restrict that in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-mfa).

Comment: Also, the email verification part is not part of MFA only the call or text is.  @StezPet

Answer (score -1):

The easiest approach for hiding elements is to use [the page UI customization feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) with styles such as:

```
#api[data-name=Unified] #forgotPassword,
#api[data-name=Unified] .divider,
#api[data-name=Unified] .create {
    display: none;
}

#api[data-name=Phonefactor] #verifyPhone {
    display: none;
}
```